# Abnormal projection shift

Tags: r, raster, projection, data-representation

I have produced and compiled random points (blue) and data points (red) that are spread across Europe - but when I try to represent them on a baseline map, I have a shift that appears between the points and the map. This can be clearly seen in the lower right part near Crete, where the red points should be **on** the island.

[image]

The baseline map is a Raster Layer and the points are kept within a data frame which contains the coordinate (longitude & latitude).

The CRS arguments for the baseline are as follows:

```
> crs(baseline_EU[[1]])    
CRS arguments:
     +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
```

but I do not know the CRS arguments for the points:

```
> crs(P.points)
[1] NA
```

I do not know how to solve this issue, so I would really appreciate your help.
Many thanks.

EDIT: here is an extract of the raw data. It contains latitude and longitude informations, plus a column that tells that it is a presence point.

[image]

Also, maybe this can helps, but following Robert Hijmans' advice I have checked the CRS arguments of the data points on QGIS:

```
EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic
```

EDIT 2:

- large picture, same CRS for points & baseline map:

[image]

- small picture, same CRS for points & baseline map:

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the (red) data points?  You can try different projections or projection parameters, but going to the source seems to be the obvious thing to do

Comment: The data comes from a csv file that my research supervisor gave me. I have edited my message to add a screenshot of the raw data.

Comment: Then you should ask them what it is or where they got it. It clearly is not ESPG:4326

Comment: Ok thanks. But still, I have tried to transform the data frame into a spatialdataframe and then I have set the same CRS as for the baseline. And when I plot the points and the baseline (same crs) I still have a shift. And if I try to plot the map, enlarge it, **and then** project the points, I obtain strange shifts. But when the picture is set to the minimal size, it seems to reduce the shift (make it disappear?) - see second edit of my question. So my question is: could this just be an artifact from the R representation tool?

Comment: Does it work if first resize the image area and then plot the raster and points again?

Comment: Sorry @Robert Hijmans, but how would you resize the image area? I have tried different things but nothing works better.

Comment: This seems to be a long running issue with overlapping data on raster plots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213453/overlay-raster-plot-using-plot-add-t-leads-to-arbitrary-misalignment-of-fin

Comment: @LucasFortini Many thanks, greatly appreciated! I had not found this question when I researched for an answer :-)